# Adding OpenCV Extra Modules to existing OpenCV VS Project

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++

I searched online and couldn't find any recommended way to add the extra openCV modules into an existing OpenCV project other than building it all from scratch.

Any recommendations on some possible ways to achieve that.

What have been done so far:

- Downloaded opencv
- Downloaded opencv-contrib
- Ran OpenCV's python cross-compilation script using the following command :
  python ../opencv/platforms/android/build_sdk.py  --extra_modules_path
  ../opencv_contrib/modules  ../opencv

What are the next steps given than i have already the opencv standard modules in my VS project and only need to add the extra contrib modules (specifically 2 modules out of them).

Comment: build from scratch

Comment: indeed, build from scratch.  follow [instructions here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/README.md)